# Another rookie question; How to implement Count() here?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I have this query:

```
SELECT mt.*, fordon.*, boende.*, elektronik.*, business.*, hem_inredning.*, hobby.*
FROM classified mt 
LEFT JOIN fordon ON fordon.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
LEFT JOIN boende ON boende.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
LEFT JOIN elektronik ON elektronik.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
LEFT JOIN business ON business.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
LEFT JOIN hem_inredning ON hem_inredning.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
LEFT JOIN hobby ON hobby.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
ORDER BY modify_date DESC
```

I need to implement a count here, to just count all rows in combination with the JOINS you see.

How should I do this?

`SELECT COUNT(mt.*, fordon.* etc) FROM` ? // This method wont work

Thanks

Comment: Shame on you for using select * in any query with a join. When you do this you are returning data you don't need (the joins fields are duplicated) and causing the server to do unnecessary work and sending more information over your network than is needed. If you do this on most queries, you are causing performance problems for literally no reason other than laziness. Very poor practice.

Comment: HLGEM, for simplification, it's common to use `SELECT *` in examples here. While the user should not use them in production code, and it's great to remind the OP, "shame on you" is jumping the gun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the `ORDER BY`, as it is not required for the `COUNT`:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM classified mt  
LEFT JOIN fordon ON fordon.classified_id = mt.classified_id  
LEFT JOIN boende ON boende.classified_id = mt.classified_id  
LEFT JOIN elektronik ON elektronik.classified_id = mt.classified_id  
LEFT JOIN business ON business.classified_id = mt.classified_id  
LEFT JOIN hem_inredning ON hem_inredning.classified_id = mt.classified_id  
LEFT JOIN hobby ON hobby.classified_id = mt.classified_id
```

Comment: And lastly, how do I retrieve the nr of rows? $res=mysql_query($query); Then what do I do?

Comment: @Camran: it will return a table with a single row and a single column.

Comment: you can add an alias to the count results and access just like any other field in a query:

SELECT Count(*) As NumberOfRecs FROM ....

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT mt.*, fordon.*, boende.*, elektronik.*, business.*,     hem_inredning.*, hobby.*
FROM classified mt 
LEFT JOIN fordon ON fordon.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
LEFT JOIN boende ON boende.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
LEFT JOIN elektronik ON elektronik.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
LEFT JOIN business ON business.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
LEFT JOIN hem_inredning ON hem_inredning.classified_id = mt.classified_id 
LEFT JOIN hobby ON hobby.classified_id = mt.classified_id) As A
```

Comment: That is a bad idea! It would result in a huge temporary table from which you do not need any data.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` ? I'm not sure what you're trying to count.

Comment: I am trying to count nr of rows found... Need it for paging... Why are the answers so different?

Comment: @Camran, are you trying to count everything in those tables? Or just a certain table? If trying to count all, SELECT COUNT(*) works

Comment: No, not all, only rows which are JOINED, check my Query

Comment: Well `COUNT(*)` counts the combination of results between the joined tables. If you need it for paging you probably just need `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mt` to get the count separately from the main JOIN query.

Comment: I agree, @Camran does not need to make JOINs for counting since all of them are left joins (assuming that there is not more than a single corresponding row in each joined table)